# update primarykey type and keep data integrity

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, linq

In a .NET MVC website using MySQL database I have a forum table with 1000 records that uses an int 
autoincreament primary key. 
I want to change the key type. I'm looking for a suggested way to update the ThreadId primarykeys to random 6 digit int keys and at the same time update the (ParentId and ParentThreadId) for the records already in the table.

I don't know if I should focus on SQL commands or Linq to do this? If Linq is the suggested way to go, the method generating the new 6 digit int key has the following signature:

```
public int GenerateKey();
```

The MySQL table has this layout and example data:

ForumTable
ThreadId int autoincreament
ParentId (int) allow Null
ParentThreadId (int) allow Null

Exemple data
ThreadId 483 | ParentId null | ParentThreadId null
ThreadId 484 | ParentId 483 | ParentThreadId 483
ThreadId 485 | ParentId 326 | ParentThreadId 325

Comment: You need to updated your database. You need to remove autoincrement for thread id since you want to start generating it. And you specify an update rule in your relationship to cascade